# No task bar in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

My task bar is gone and I don't know, I asked IntelliJ whether they can help me, but the answer wasn't useful. My Android Studio looks now like in the Screenshot. I also tried to uninstall and reinstall it and tried to change the settings.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PZNY.png)

When I created a new project, it looked like this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcoxG.png)

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 4 simple steps for this:

1. **Press Shift double time**. It will open up the popped up window.
2. Under Actions, **type main menu**.
3. A toggle button labelled **View | appearance: Main Menu - OFF** appears.
4. **Hit that toggle button** to make it ON.

Voila! your Main Menu toolbar is back.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a search using `Ctrl+Shift+A` shortcut, then type `main menu` it will show you a menu like this, from `View -> Appearance` you can show or hide any option

[image]